A continuous analogue of the notion of Hilbert basis
Let $X$ be a locally compact space, let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $\beta:X\to H$ be a continuous function such that the linear subspace of $H$ spanned by $\beta(X)$ is dense in $H$. I would like to know if it is possible to use the function $\beta$ like a Hilbert basis of $H$ in order to decompose vectors.
More precisely, my question is:

Does there exist a Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that for every $\xi\in H$, the map $x\mapsto\langle\xi,\beta(x)\rangle\beta(x)$ from $X$ to $H$ is Pettis-$\mu$-integrable and satisfies $\xi=\int_X\langle\xi,\beta(x)\rangle\beta(x)\,d\mu(x)$ ?


Let $H$ be two dimensional, let $X = \{1,2\}$, and substitute $\xi = \beta(1)$ in your proposed integral formula for $\xi$. This formula together with the linear independence of $(\beta(1), \beta(2))$ shows that $\beta(1)$ is orthogonal to $\beta(2)$.
But you did not assume any mutual orthogonality of the vectors $\beta(x)$, so the answer to your question no, in general.
